# Text going outside of div Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I am little new in HTML and bootstrap. I am facing weird issue in my website.

```
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
        <a href="https://stag.example.com/gu/post/happy-new-year-2023-68400"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500/" class="img-fluid blog-img h-100 lzy_img" alt="Happy New Year 2023" width="100%" height="100%">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
        <div class="blog_content d-flex bg-dark text-white flex-column bg-black h-100 text-center pt-3 pb-3 px-3 mx-3">
            <h5 class="mb-0 border-0">નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની શરૂઆત </h5>
            <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center align-items-center mb-0 h-100">
                <div class="flip-card h-100">
                    <div class="flip-card-inner h-100">
                        <div class="flip-card-front d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <p class="">નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની<br> શરૂઆત કંઈક એવી થાય,<br> તમારા જીવનમાં ખુશીઓ ફેલાય,<br> આનંદ મંગલથી દરેક દિવસ<br> પસાર થાય એવી હાર્દિક<br> શુભકામનાઓ !!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flip-card-back d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <p class="">nutan varsh 2023 ni<br> sharuat kaik evi thay,<br> tamar jivanam khushio felay,<br> anand mangalathi darek divas<br> pasar thay evi hardik<br> shubhakamanao !!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="time d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center align-items-end mt-auto pt-3">
                <div class="left text-start">
                    <h6 class="mb-0"><a class="link-bold" href="https://stag.example.com/gu/festival/happy-new-year-2023">નવા વરસની શુભકામનાઓ</a></h6>
                    <p class="mb-0"><small>1 day ago</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <span class="copy"><img src="https://stag.example.com/assets/images/copy.png" class="mx-1 social" alt="share quote" width="24" height="24"></span>
                    <a href="https://stag.example.com/gu/post/happy-new-year-2023-68400"><img src="https://stag.example.com/assets/images/share.png" class="mx-1 social" alt="share quote" width="24" height="24"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have CSS like below

```
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flip-card-front {
    background:rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.99);
    color:#000;
    font-weight:600;
}
.flip-card-back {
  color:#000;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background:rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.99);
  font-weight:600;
}
```

I have marked that in DESKTOP its showing perfect text but in mobile its going outside of parent div
like this image
[image]

in DESKTOP its looking perfect like this image

[image]

I have not added any mobile specific CSS. I have added code in [codeplay](https://www.codeply.com/p/RFpoITHkjM) for debug it.

I have also marked that if I remove flip-card div and put text, its working fine. I am using bootstrap 5.2.

Let me know if someone here can help me to correct it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the text has `absolute` positioning which takes it out of flow, therefore the parent is not adjusting to contain it.

Assuming that the goal is to contain the text in `flip-card` and keep both sides stacked together, perhaps try use `grid` display on `flip-card-inner` and place the 2 sides in the same cell, instead of `absolute` positioning:

```
.flip-card-inner {
  /*  Added this */
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```
.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  /*  Added these and removed "position: absolute" */
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Full example:

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  /*  Added this */
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  /*  Added these */
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.99);
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.flip-card-back {
  color: #000;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.99);
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
    <a href="https://stag.example.com/gu/post/happy-new-year-2023-68400"
      ><img
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500/"
        class="img-fluid blog-img h-100 lzy_img"
        alt="Happy New Year 2023"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
    <div
      class="blog_content d-flex bg-dark text-white flex-column bg-black h-100 text-center pt-3 pb-3 px-3 mx-3"
    >
      <h5 class="mb-0 border-0">નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની શરૂઆત</h5>
      <div
        class="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center align-items-center mb-0 h-100"
      >
        <div class="flip-card h-100">
          <div class="flip-card-inner h-100">
            <div
              class="flip-card-front d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
            >
              <p class="">
                નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની<br />
                શરૂઆત કંઈક એવી થાય,<br />
                તમારા જીવનમાં ખુશીઓ ફેલાય,<br />
                આનંદ મંગલથી દરેક દિવસ<br />
                પસાર થાય એવી હાર્દિક<br />
                શુભકામનાઓ !!
              </p>
            </div>
            <div
              class="flip-card-back d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
            >
              <p class="">
                nutan varsh 2023 ni<br />
                sharuat kaik evi thay,<br />
                tamar jivanam khushio felay,<br />
                anand mangalathi darek divas<br />
                pasar thay evi hardik<br />
                shubhakamanao !!
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="time d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center align-items-end mt-auto pt-3"
      >
        <div class="left text-start">
          <h6 class="mb-0">
            <a
              class="link-bold"
              href="https://stag.example.com/gu/festival/happy-new-year-2023"
              >નવા વરસની શુભકામનાઓ</a
            >
          </h6>
          <p class="mb-0"><small>1 day ago</small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <span class="copy"
            ><img
              src="https://stag.example.com/assets/images/copy.png"
              class="mx-1 social"
              alt="share quote"
              width="24"
              height="24"
          /></span>
          <a href="https://stag.example.com/gu/post/happy-new-year-2023-68400"
            ><img
              src="https://stag.example.com/assets/images/share.png"
              class="mx-1 social"
              alt="share quote"
              width="24"
              height="24"
          /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its look like there no any changes. Looking same like before.

Comment: @Manisha Thanks for the feedback, I added a running snippet to the answer and hopefully it could help.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, it have solved my puzzle. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
    background: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.99);
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.flip-card-back {
    color: #000;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.99);
    font-weight: 600;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) { 

body .bg-dark {
    height: 400px !important;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
        <a href="https://stag.example.com/gu/post/happy-new-year-2023-68400"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500/" class="img-fluid blog-img h-100 lzy_img" alt="Happy New Year 2023" width="100%" height="100%">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3 mt-md-0">
        <div class="blog_content d-flex bg-dark text-white flex-column bg-black h-100 text-center pt-3 pb-3 px-3 mx-3">
            <h5 class="mb-0 border-0">નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની શરૂઆત </h5>
            <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center align-items-center mb-0 h-100">
                <div class="flip-card h-100">
                    <div class="flip-card-inner h-100">
                        <div class="flip-card-front d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <p class="">નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની<br> શરૂઆત કંઈક એવી થાય,<br> તમારા જીવનમાં ખુશીઓ ફેલાય,<br> આનંદ મંગલથી દરેક દિવસ<br> પસાર થાય એવી હાર્દિક<br> શુભકામનાઓ !!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flip-card-back d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <p class="">nutan varsh 2023 ni<br> sharuat kaik evi thay,<br> tamar jivanam khushio felay,<br> anand mangalathi darek divas<br> pasar thay evi hardik<br> shubhakamanao !!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="time d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center align-items-end mt-auto pt-3">
                <div class="left text-start">
                    <h6 class="mb-0"><a class="link-bold" href="https://stag.example.com/gu/festival/happy-new-year-2023">નવા વરસની શુભકામનાઓ</a></h6>
                    <p class="mb-0"><small>1 day ago</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <span class="copy"><img src="https://stag.example.com/assets/images/copy.png" class="mx-1 social" alt="share quote" width="24" height="24"></span>
                    <a href="https://stag.example.com/gu/post/happy-new-year-2023-68400"><img src="https://stag.example.com/assets/images/share.png" class="mx-1 social" alt="share quote" width="24" height="24"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its looking good but I can not have fixed height because I have text lines more sometime

Comment: ok happy to know someone helped you